# jQuery.scrollSpeed.js resetting page offset

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, scrolltop

So my problem is, when you go onto the view item page of my website, I have jQuery on pageload that makes the page scroll down 200px, but the jQuery.scrollSpeed.js resets the page offset back to the top of the page when they use their scroll wheel.

Sorry if that was a bad explanation, you can see the problem yourself if you go here: http://www.coastalculture.matttruscott.co.nz/view.php?item=20

I am not that experienced in javascript/jQuery so I don't know how to prevent this from happening.

JQuery script below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jQuery.scrollSpeed.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {  
        jQuery.scrollSpeed(50, 800);
    });
</script>
<script>
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    $('body,html').animate({
            scrollTop: 200 ,
            }, 1200
        );
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There seems to be an issue in the `scrollSpeed` component.

The only way elegant way I could find to fix the issue is to modify the `scrollSpeed` code directly.

It currently looks like this at the start:

```
  jQuery.scrollSpeed = function (step, speed, easing) {

    var $document = $(document),
        $window = $(window),
        $body = $('html, body'),
        option = easing || 'default',
        root = 0,
        scroll = false,
        scrollY,
        scrollX,
        view;

    if (window.navigator.msPointerEnabled)
```

Change this to:

```
  jQuery.scrollSpeed = function (step, speed, easing) {

    var $document = $(document),
        $window = $(window),
        $body = $('html, body'),
        option = easing || 'default',
        root = 0,
        scroll = false,
        scrollY = $document.height() > $window.height(),
        scrollX = $document.width() > $window.width(),
        view;

    if (window.navigator.msPointerEnabled)
```

Note the `scrollY` and `scrollX` start values.

Comment: Thanks! Helped to solve issue with page offset after scrolling down and reloading page.

Comment: Thank so much,

I got a problem when I click HOME button. Are you have solution ?

Answer (score 0):

It is solve issue with page offset after scrolling down and reloading page or if you use: `$window.off('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll');`(for disable or enable scroll)

Change this to: `root = 0` on **root = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop**

```
var $document = $(document),`enter code here`
    $window = $(window),
    $body = $('html, body'),
    option = easing || 'default',
    root = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop,
    scroll = false,
    scrollY,
    scrollX,
    view;
```